# Having a Braintree custom form with CB and PayPal

Tags: javascript, .net, paypal, braintree

We don't want to use Braintree's dropin form to stick with our UI.
So far, our payment form with only CC fields was working great. We were setting up braintree.js with:

```
braintree.setup(token, "custom", {
  id: "options"
});
```

Then came PayPal and we added the PayPal container to the setup:

```
braintree.setup(token, "custom", {
  id: "options",
  paypal: {
    container: "paypal-button"
  }
});
```

Everything was working locally until last Saturday. By digging I found out that the payment_method_nonce wasn't sent to the server anymore when filling the CC fields:
[image: missing nonce server side]

although the nonce input is present client-side in my form!!!
[image]

So what's the matter here?
Is braintree.js interacting somehow with the form submission? How come this payment_method_nonce is sometimes retrieved server-side (when paying via PayPal) and sometimes not (when paying via CC)?

Thanks

Comment: I work at Braintree. Are you still having this issue? It's possible it's related to a problem we recently fixed. If you are still having it, your best bet is to [contact our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).

Comment: The issue is fixed; I already contacted your support btw.
I posted my problem here first because it's generally safe to assume that your code is the problem, not braintree's ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, turns out the issue was on Braintree's side.

Using https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js with braintree.js version greater than 2.2.4 solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. You need to use "custom" as the integration method when you are using your own credit card form with an additional PayPal button:

```
braintree.setup(token, "custom", {
  id: "options",
  paypal: {
    container: "paypal-button"
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @mrak, sorry for the spelling mistake in my second code area but I have this issue when using "custom" like you mentioned.
So the error doesn't come from this.

Comment: How did you figure this out? I can't find proper documentation for braintree.setup anywhere. Is there anywhere that defines what options are available, or a standard API documentation? I'm beyond the "wizard" walkthroughs on their insultingly simple and disorganized website.